# Constraints in Excel Solver

Tags: linear-programming

I am using Excel Solver.  I have decision variables $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$ with the constraints that $A \leq B \leq C \leq D \leq E$.  How do I specify this type of constraint in the Solver dialogue box.

Update 10/3:  Yes, that makes sense and I did try that to no avail.  I am now thinking that solver may not be a valid method for the problem at hand.  The
question requires using a LP approach for fitting a curve to the $(a,b)$ data.
[image]

Comment: Split it in 4 constraints: $A\leq B, B \leq C, C\leq D, D\leq E$. Alright?

Answer (score 0):

You can linearize the problem by introducing a new variable $z_i$ for each absolute value, minimizing $\sum_i z_i$, and including constraints
\begin{align}
z_i &\ge y_i - b_i \\
z_i &\ge -(y_i - b_i)
\end{align}

Comment: OK.  I have read that absolute functions can be linearized as you indicate.  The part that I am having difficulty with is how this is all entered into Excel Solver.  For example, what would the objective function and a typical constraint look like?  That might help me get started.  New to this subject. Thanks.